# Domain of set as 1-ary relation

Tags: set-theory

In my course text, it says "a relation is a set of n-tuples, and a set is a 1-ary relation".

I was not quite sure about the details of that last part, so here is what I assume to know:

- a 1-ary relation R is a subset of some domain D
- a set S is a collection of objects

If we view the set as a 1-ary relation, does this imply that the domain of that relation consists (only) of the elements of S?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It strikes me as somewhat perverse to view sets (which are fundamental in set theory) in terms of relations, but it's true that $1$-ary relations are essentially sets, and the domain of said $1$-ary relation will just be the set it corresponds to.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Theo Bendit if you would like to include your comment as an answer, I will tag it as the solution to the question.